# Handling different routes (with different params) for the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, routes

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

I have a intermediate table X to map Elements from table A to elements from table B.

This table X contains also many columns regarding properties of this mapping. The uniqueness of a record in table X is not just the id od A and id od B but also a unique identifier that represents the mapping.

When trying to update a property of table X, I added to routes:

```
map.A :only=>[:none] do |a|
    a.resources B :controller=>X :only[:update]
end

map.resources x :only=>[:update]
```

So this basically gives me to possible urls to access the update method of my X controller.

**QUESTION:**

My question is: how can I tell when the controller was accessed by passing A and B or just X identifier? I know that looking at the params I can check if A is present and if not then it mus be X but this is not very practical/secure. If it gets more complicated I will need multiple ifs to detect the exact case.

Even worst, imagine that for some reason I have another route like:

```
map.resources Y :controller=>X :only[:update]
```

Then in my params hash I would just have :id so and if condition wouldn't even work...

**COMMENTS:**

I wish there was a `:key` option for the routes so you could rename the keys in the parameters hash but from what I have read in Rails 2 there is no such a thing and I would like to avoid plugins if possible. Isn't there a better way than if cases or parsing the url to tell what parameters where passed so I can look up my database?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This *seems* like a case where you'd want to actually have two different actions handling the cases if it's that much of a concern, but you *can* hack around this by using the defaults hash -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults -- to specify a parameter that tells you which one you're following to get to the same case.

What I mean by two different actions is having an `:action => update_from_a` in the route and an appropriate method in the controller in addition to the normal `:update` method.  Some of this advice may be rails 3-specific.

Comment: Well, that is how I had it originally but in an intent of best practices and following RESTful guides, I am updating the status of X and therefore that should be a PUT request to a specific resource (a unique X in this case) no matter what property you are updating. This would also save code and be more logical I think.

Comment: With it set up this way, to the outside world you are providing a single resource and it is only two separate actions internally. The reason I put "that much of a concern" here in the answer is that figuring out what to do based on the parameters is fine.  It's largely up to your taste and style which is right.

Comment: You actually right in the part that to the outside world it's still a single resource, good point! The only down part is still overloading the routes file with all the possible cases...

Thanks!